# jQuery performance fullscreen fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to create a dark overlay which fades in just like most modal-box plugins. I do so by having a `<div id="overlay">` and the following CSS:

```
#overlay {
  background: black;
  display: none;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

I animate this #overlay using jQuery:

```
$('#overlay').fadeIn(400);
```

The performance of this fadein however is not optimal. When fading in at a resolution of 1920x1080 pixels I would estimate an FPS of about 10/15. Is there a better way to make this animation go more smooth?

Comment: What browser? What version? **It makes a huge difference.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the frames-per-second as of version jQuery 1.4.3. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/) link. Playing around with a higher FPS may cause an overall smoother animation.

Javascript animation processing is not very smooth on some of the older browsers (IE6-7).

Answer (score -2):

What about using low-level `.animate()` function? It *might* be better..

Comment: Random speculation, completely untested - not a useful answer

Comment: You're right, but I have no means of testing on that resolution.

Comment: `fadeIn()` is [just a wrapper for a call to `.animate()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L270) with the properties predefined.